# Best practice to wrap existing API with express (WordPress API in this case)

Tags: node.js, wordpress, api, express, woocommerce

I have an existing REST API for a particular purpose. Now, I have to get data from a WordPress website to use data from it.
I've never wrapped an API in an existing one before, and I would like to ensure that I'm doing well, because I naively did the same as writing the api rest.

Here's my project structure :

```
backend
|──config
|   |── db.config.js
|   |── wp-credentials.config.js
|──controllers
|   |── task.controller.js
|   |── wp.controller.js
|──models
|   |── wp.models.js
|   |── task.models.js
|──routes
|   |── task.routes.js
|   |── wp.routes.js
|server.js
```

I put API key in wp-credentials.
Then, in wp.model.js, I did (I'm interested in order from Woocommerce so I create an Order class):

```
const WooCommerceRestApi = require("@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api").default;

const WooCommerce = new WooCommerceRestApi({
  url: 'https://example.com',
  consumerKey: 'ck_example',
  consumerSecret: 'cs_example',
  wpAPI: true,
  version: 'wc/v3'
});

module.exports = WooCommerce;

// constructor
const Order = function(orders) {
  
};

Order.getAll = result => {
    WooCommerce.get("orders")
    .then((response) => {
        result(null, response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {            
        console.log("error: ", error);
        result(null, error);
        return;
    })
}

module.exports = Order;
```

The controller look like that :

```
const Order = require("../models/orders.model.js");

exports.findAll = (_, res) => {
       Order.getAll((err, data) => {
           if (err)
            res.status(500).send({
                message:
                    err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving order."
            });
            else {
                res.send(data);
            }
       })
}
```

Then, i wrap the route like that :

```
module.exports = app => {

    const orders = require("../controllers/wordpress.controller.js");
    
    // Retrieve all orders
    app.get("/orders", orders.findAll);

};
```

Comment: It isn't clear to me what question you're wanting to be answered.

Comment: If it's a great practice to do like I did. How I did is a great one for writting Rest API, but is it for wrapping an existing API? Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: Just think about it, what do you want to abstract away from the user when you wrap another API.

Also you might want to have error handling (Check what kind of error the Wordpress might give you and handle it properly)